# Why does `xstring`s `\StrBefore` work, but not `\IfBeginWith`?

Tags: conditionals, labels, xstring, showkeys

I'm currently using the package `showkeys` to debug the labels in my document. Using the command `\renewcommand{\showkeyslabelformat}[1]{...}` one can customise the display of the labels. I want to handle equation labels (labels that start with `eq:`) differently than other labels. Therefore, I wanted to test whether the label starts with `eq` using `xstring`. Somehow this does not seem to work.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

% FIRST BLOCK
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{%
  \fbox{\small\ttfamily\StrBefore{#1}{:}}}

\textbf{Lemma.} \label{lemma:no_equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:my_equation}
    \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-1} = 2
\end{equation}

% SECOND BLOCK
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{%
  \fbox{\small\ttfamily\IfBeginWith{#1}{eq}{equation}{no equation}}}
  
\textbf{Lemma.} \label{lemma:no_equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:my_equation}
    \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-1} = 2
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, `xstring` is able to correctly parse the first part of the labels. Still it does not work to condition on the beginning of the string. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions in `expl3` are category code agnostic.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\beginwithTF}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = string to search in, #2 = string to search, #3 = true, #4 = false
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A #2\: } { #1 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{%
  \fbox{\small\ttfamily\beginwithTF{#1}{eq}{equation}{no equation}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma} \label{lemma:B}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B}
    \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-1} = 2
\end{equation}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

With `\regex_match:nnTF` we look whether the given regular expression (first argument) matches the given string (second argument). I've kept the order of arguments in `\IfBeginWith`, though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I also found out, that the starred macros in `xstring` do not take the catcodes into account. Therefore the original `\IfBeginWith` can just be replaced by the starred version.

Answer (score 5):

showkeys makes things safe with `\meaning` so that labels with `&` or `$` or other special character do not blow up when typeset. so you are comparing catcode 12 ("other") `eq` with catcode 11 (letter) `eq` and these are not equal.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem. Do you see a workaround here?

Comment: you could use a catcode 12 eq as your test or use `\pdfstrcmp` (which does catcode-ignored comparisons or ....)

Comment: Thank you! I also found out, that the starred macros in `xstring` do not take the catcodes into account. Therefore the original `\IfBeginWith` can just be replaced by the starred version.